# Samba has a module vfs_full_audit, what does each object actually mean within the module?

Tags: linux, logs, samba, smb, protocols

The module vfs_full_audit in Samba lists objects that can be added to the module to increase the logging specificity or verbosity generally of syscalls. Example:

```
# defaults for auditing
full_audit:priority = notice
full_audit:facility = local6
full_audit:failure = create_file open opendir rmdir unlink unlinkat connect connectpath disconnect
full_audit:success = rename opendir rmdir unlink open create_file opendir unlinkat connect connectpath disconnect
full_audit:prefix = %U|%d|%u|%R|%I|%S
```

However in the man page located here: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_full_audit.8.html

It fails to define explicitly what each object actually does - I understand that some of them are fairly obvious such as "open" or "rmdir" but a sentence just describing what each part does would be very useful for more questionable ones such as "kernel_flock"

Does anyone know of any resource/URL that defines these values explicitly? Or perhaps this has been asked previously by one of you and had data back from Sernet detailing it?

Thanks for looking ;)

Comment: check this https://www.maravento.com/2021/12/samba-full-audit.html and this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1950803

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly, the full audit module changed a lot (and the docs didn't kept up) and now It just bombs you with unuseful data. IMMV, if you want more than unlinkat and renameat (delete and rename), you will receive lots of pointless data.

If you misstype one single action (which is easy because the docs are outdated), it will log everything (ie: full_audit:success all), and then you will see the log avalanche.

If you are using samba 4, forget the audit logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.
It's because I was using the "old names".
`rmdir` doesn't exist anymore for example.

Try using only `mkdirat`, `renameat`, `unlinkat`...
From what I understand, if you put names that do not exist, Samba will display all the logs.

See [`man 8 vfs_full_audit`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/samba-vfs-modules/vfs_full_audit.8) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Bitten by this today, an upgrade from 4.16 to 4.17 and a share that suddenly won't allow anyone access.   RTFM carefully, and check any actions.  Unlike previous two answers, with Samba 4.17 typos DO NOT result in "log everything" they result in login to that share being disabled

"If an unknown operation name is used (for example an operation name is miss-spelled), the module will fail to load and clients will be refused connections to a share using this module."